# Can a increasing function from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be bounded?

Tags: functions

A function $$f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$$ be increasing and yet be bounded?

Comment: Of course.  1 - 1/x is an obvious one.  Okay that is only defined increasing on x > 0 but it can be tweak.  $1- (1/2)^x$ if x $\ge$ 0; $-(1 - (1/2)^{|x|}$ if $x < 0$.  Is another .  There are gazillions of them.  Any function strictly below a horizontal asymptote.  Any bounded increasing sequence can be extended to such a function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. $f(x)=\arctan x$ has derivative $1/(1+x^2)$ which is positive for all $x$, hence $f$ is strictly increasing (proof: mean value theorem). But $f$ is bounded above and below, by $\pi/2$ and $-\pi/2$ respectively.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x) = 1 - a^x$, $0 < a < 1; x \ge 0$;  $f(x) = -f(|x|); x < 0$.

There's millions of them.